# How to switch context in Blender python?

Tags: python, blender

Good day,
I'm very new to the Blender API.

Ultimately, I am trying to get the currently selected object. I know this is available `bpy.context.selected_objects`. However, I'm running my script from a python file and the context object is different. in my current context the `selected_objects` does not exist.

I've searched around and at most I've been able to find that you can edit in which context some operators are run by overriding their settings. But `bpy.context.selected_objects` is not an operator.

Perhaps there is a method or operator inside `bpy.data` which returns the selected object? I can't seem to find the part of the documentation which shows what attributes are exposed inside `bpy.data` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=bpy.data.&check_keywords=yes&area=default#

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As your running this from blender scripting possibly using `bpy.context.active_object` rather then `bpy.context.selected_objects` might work better.

There can be an active object when no objects are selected, here's more info on them: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27396/whats-the-difference-among-object-active-object-and-selected-objects

It's also quite hard to tell what could be going on without more details on the internal functionings, so attaching code would be usefull.